# JQuery not updating input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got an issue trying to update an inputs value using JQuery.

Here is the code I have at the minute:

```
var rtypeid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('rtype-id');
$("#roomlink").val(rtypeid);
```

And heres the HTML:

```
<input class="form-control hidden" id="roomlink" name="roomlink">
```

I have another line under that which I am successfully using to change the title of my Modal window to be the room type which the user has selected however this has no affect (they use the same variable, header gets changed after the input)

Strange thing is that I can paste the code into Chromes dev tools, run it and it will change the value.

Any help would be much apreciated! Thanks.

Comment: is it fired on a onclick event or anything like that?

Comment: Its fired when the modal window shows 

" $('#add_rate_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { "

Comment: do `console.log(e.relatedTarget)` what does it return?

Comment: It returns: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:13
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)

the thing is that it changes the header of the modal which uses the same variable the input is supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

Right, sorted it - the variable (**var** rtypeid) was set in a function and was not accessible to the insertion/header change funciton.
taking the var off of it and referencing it via window.variablename sorted it.